# Finding all paths between two nodes on a DAG

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG that has the following adjacency list

```
L | G, B, P
G | P, I
B | I
P | I
I | R
R | \
```

I want to find all paths from `L` to `R`. I know that I have to do some kind of DFS, and this is what I have so far. (Excuse the Javascript)

```
function dfs(G, start_vertex) {

    const fringe = []
    const visited = new Set()
    const output = []
    fringe.push(start_vertex)

    while (fringe.length != 0) {
        const vertex = fringe.pop()
        if (!visited.has(vertex)) {
            output.push(vertex)
            for (neighbor in G[vertex].neighbors) {
                fringe.push(neighbor)
            }
            visited.add(vertex)
        }
    }

    return output
}
```

The output of `dfs(G, "L")` is `[ 'L', 'P', 'I', 'R', 'B', 'G' ]` which is indeed a depth first traversal of this graph, but not the result I'm looking for. After doing some searching, I realize there may be a recursive solution, but there were some comments about this problem being "NP-hard" and something about "exponential paths" which I don't understand.

Comment: The problem in general case isn't even NP (a solution can't be checked in polynomial type since it has non-polynomial size), but this shouldn't concern you.

Comment: @Abstraction good, because I can eyeball a solution in 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed np-hard because the number of possible paths between two nodes is exponential to the number of nodes. so no way around having a worst-case  exponential runtime.

Comment: Just because the first solution that comes to mind is exponential it doesn't mean the problem is exponential. A lot of DP problems are exponential too if implemented in a naive way.

Comment: Well, I don't mention a specific solution here. I just say that in the worst case scenario (runtime-wise) there might be an exponential number of paths (exponential to the number of nodes) so even if you find a solution in which finding a path in O(1) time, you have exponential number of such paths, which means you need an exponential runtime to find all of them. I think it's quite clear that finding more than one path in O(1) is impossible since you have to at least return a pointer to that path, which is O(1) per path already

Answer (score 1):

All paths with start `head` to vertex `vertex` can be split into paths with heads `head||v` where `v` is adjacent to final vertex of `head`, unless final vertex of `head` is already `vertex`: (pseudo-javascript, can have syntax problems)

```
function print_all_rec(G, head, vertex){
  if(head[head.length-1] == vertex){
    print(head); //we're here
    return;
  }
  for(v in head[head.length-1].neighbors){
    var newHead = head; newHead.append(v);
    print_all_rec(G, newHead, vertex);
  }
}

function print_all_routes(G, from, to){
  var start = [];
  start.append(from);
  print_all_rec(G, start, to);
}
```