# Is DFS (Depth-first search) algorithm applied on an adjacency matrix the ideal solution to list all root-to-leaf paths of a graph?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am creating a function in Ruby to list all the possible paths that a business process may be executed. Look at the diagram below that represents a sample process:

[image]

I want the output to be like:

```
[
  [[Task 1],[Task 2], [Task 4], [Task 6]],
  [[Task 1],[Task 3],[Task 5],[Task 6]]
]
```

So, I created a method to represent it as an adjacency matrix. It works just fine.

Now I want to work on an algorithm to extract all those paths. I was gonna implement the DFS, but I'm not so sure anymore if this is the right way to approach it since I'm not doing an actual search - I am only listing the paths.

Comment: This is a DAG not a tree

Comment: DFS will work just fine, why are you not sure whether it's "the right way"?

Comment: @Dukeling because, in a first moment, I thought DFS was only for searching for a specific vertex. I have little knowledge in algorithms and graph theory too.

Comment: @marvel308 yes, and as soon as one user pointed that out I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is np-hard because the number of possible paths between two nodes is exponential to the number of nodes since the example given is a DAG instead of a tree. so no way around having a worst-case exponential runtime. DFS/BFS would be the best way to go please refer to 
[Finding all paths between two nodes on a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072300/finding-all-paths-between-two-nodes-on-a-dag) 
[Enumerating all paths in a directed acyclic graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262712/enumerating-all-paths-in-a-directed-acyclic-graph)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. I didn't even know what a DAG was. I'm gonna read thoroughly those links and I will give feedback later